# UINavigationBar Custom Title View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am using iOS 5 `UINavigationBar`'s `UIAppearance` protocol in order to customise all my navigation bars.

Here is my customisation function:

```
- (void)customizeApperance
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setAlpha:0.7];
    UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleView:titleView];
}
```

I have two problems:

- The first is that the colour not appearing as `clearColor` but black. Any suggestions?
- The title view is not appearing at all. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) shows how to do that by adding a: `[[rootViewController navigationItem] setTitleView: [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"miniLogo.png"]]]` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. But the problem with this is that the title view would only be added in the root view controller. I am using a `UINavigationController` and when I tired to replace the `rootViewController` with `navigationController` (the name of my navigation controller in AppDelegate), I cannot see the title view at all. How can I fix that? Why isn't it working in `customizeApperance()`? Isn't the whole point of using appearance is to just create a title view once (as I did above the function) and have it global in all navigation bars? How can I achieve that?

Comment: This post might help you.
[custom-uinavigationbar-background][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[UIColor clearColor]` is a fully transparent color (alpha = 0). Setting that as tint color makes the (black) background shine through. Perhaps you want `[UIColor whiteColor]` ?

`titleView` is a property of `UINavigationItem`, and each view controller has it's own `navigationItem`. Therefore you cannot set a title view globally. But you can set the background image of `UINavigationBar` with the appearance protocol, perhaps that helps:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I actually wanted `clearColor` so that the background behind it is shown transparently. Can that be done?

Comment: @Darksky: Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;` .

Comment: @MartinR that works for making the bar translucent, however, the buttons are still solid black.  See the image in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081203/custom-background-transparent-background-on-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: @Gujamin: Thank you for the info. My problem was that I did not know what Darksky wanted to achieve exactly. And I do not know if he still needs an answer for this, there was no feedback for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `titleView.opaque = NO;`? If that's set to `YES` (i.e. by default, since you're using initWithImage:), the drawing system will assume your view fills its entire bounds, and won't bother drawing anything that overlaps its frame.

Answer (score 0):

setTitleView: is a method on NavigationItem. But you are calling it on navigation bar