# Custom uibarbuttonitem image to blend with background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am making a custom UI for Navigation bar and I have a question exactly as asked in this post

[Custom background/transparent background on UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081203/custom-background-transparent-background-on-uibarbuttonitem)

In StoryBoard I tried every sort of combination to make my UIbarbuttonitem tint transparent or clear color but I still see this ugly black button (see then + sign). How can I achieve the effect of transparency so that it looks like my button is blended in with the background?

My screenshot

[image]

Some other app screenshot. Look how nice this looks?!

[image]

Note here the + image is my own custom png img of 20 x 20 pixels with transparent/blank background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that and more using the new appearance API introduced in iOS 5.

Basically you set the appearance for your UI once and it gets reflected in the whole program.

Here is an example for the `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
// You can also use stretchable images
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myCoolBarButton.png"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you cannot use iOS 5, then you have to build those programmatically like this:

```
// Create a custom button with an image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCoolBarButton.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

// Create a custom UIBarButtonItem with the button
UIBarButtonItem aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
```

Anyway, here are a few links with good tutorials on the appearance subject

[User Interface Customization in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

[How To Make Your App Stand Out With The New iOS 5 Appearance API](http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-your-app-stand-out-with-the-new-ios-5-appearance-api/)

EDIT:
Just for clarification, it is much easier to do with custom images than playing around with colors, gradients and transparency.

Comment: iska, myCoolBarButton.png is some streatched background image and not the actual + sign right? I am using iOS 5 and only supporting that iOS and up.

Comment: @SamBudda yes it is. It is the background image that you want to use for the UIBarButton, it can be anything. You can also use normal, ie. non-stretchable, images. For that just leave the resizableImageWithCapInsets part out.

Comment: very nice. thank you. the only problem now is that I don't see a border around my + button.

Comment: @SamBudda You're welcome. Usually you have to use well designed images, preferably with borders and gradients. If you follow the tutorials in the links, you can download the sample projects and inspect the images used. Maybe make something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with tint. You will have to set both the backgroundImage of the navigation bar and the backgroundImage of the bar button item, so that they harmonize as desired.

When drawing the background image of the bar button item you may have to draw the *entire* button including the rounded rect outine and the shadowing of the rounded rect outine, but this is not difficult, and when you've done it once you've reusable code forever.

Comment: Matt, I am assuming we are not talking about photoshop here in order to draw some border around my 20x20 pix image. Are you talking about some piece of code that achieves this transparency? If so can you please share the link / code?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about drawing a button shape in code, if that turns out to be needed. But there isn't some specific code, nor do I think you'd necessarily need Photoshop; things like gradients and shadows are easy to achieve using iOS drawing. Here's the chapter from my book where I describe how to draw: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html And in iOS 6, with the new CIFilters, you can do even more powerful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think your png image with + sign does not contain alpha channel. I have transparent image and it's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Tom, can you upload your sample transparent image. I will try it out and see how it looks at my end. thank you